# JSON Serialization takes a very long time

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net

I have two ViewModels (Product and Part):

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }       

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class PartViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I run an EF Core query that returns 1727 Products with at least 1 Part per product. An example of a return of 1 of these would serialize to JSON as such:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":8761,
      "Name":"Product Name 1",
      "Description":"This is a product",
      "IsActive":true,
      "Parts":[  
         {  
            "Id":103767,
            "Name":"Name 1"
            "IsActive":true
         },
         {  
            "Id":156436,
            "Name":"Name 2",
            "IsActive":true
         },
         {  
            "Id":109436,
            "Name":"Name 3",
            "IsActive":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Now, this works well with a query where I .Take(10), albeit seemingly slow, but when I try and serialize 1727 records, it bogs down and a five minute wait doesn't even complete the serialization process.

I tried using Json.Net as such:

```
var ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
```

I only decided to try and use JsonConvert from Json.Net because, in my Controller Action, when attempting to return a JsonResult, the following code to convert my object to JSON had the same efficiency issue:

```
return Json(products);
```

I get the products via EF Core as such:

```
var products = _context.Products.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Where(w => w.IsActive  //all products are active
            && (w.Parts.Count(c => c.IsActive) > 0)) //remove parts that are
            .Select(pr => new ProductViewModel
            {
                Id = pr.Id,
                Name = pr.Name,
                Description = pr.Description,
                IsActive = pr.IsActive,
                Parts = pr.Parts.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Where(w => w.IsActive)  //all parts are active
                .Select(prt => new PartViewModel
                {
                    Id = prt.Id,
                    Name = prt.Name,
                    IsActive = prt.IsActive,
                })
            }).ToList();
```

What can I do?

Comment: Read [ask], show how exactly you obtain `products`.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the serialization process that is taking so long? Also you probably want to implement some sort of paging on your server to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: I added the query, @CodeCaster

Comment: Since you're saying it takes a very long time, what are the metrics? *How slow*?

Comment: [similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/1450752/1052178) The query may not be optimal, but the de-serialization takes longest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialization is not the big deal, it's easy to notice now that you have added the LINQ query that the issue is the poor SQL Entity Framework will generate from it.

First of all, you should be using **eager loading** to join your products table with the parts table. You can do that simply by adding an `Include` method call.

```
_context.Products.Include(p => p.Parts)
```

If this is not done the query is actually doing N + 1 queries. You should use a simple trick to watch the actual SQL queries your query is doing adding this code to your `DbContext`. (Do this only if you are using EF6, EF Core does query logging for you.)

```
public YourDBContext()
{
   #if DEBUG   
   this.Database.Log = msg =>
   {
       Debugger.Log(1, "ALL", "EF DB SQL: " + msg + Environment.NewLine);
   };
   #endif
}
```

Another condition that is doing the query take long is `.Where(w => w.IsActive && (w.Parts.Count(c => c.IsActive) > 0))`. I guess Entity Framework is generating a HAVING Clause, but it would help if you posted the generated SQL to optimize the query.

Finally, a microoptimization in your `Select` method, would be to change the Parts property fetch expression by.

```
// other properties ...
Parts = pr.Parts.Where(w => w.IsActive).OrderBy(o => o.Name),
// other properties ...
```

This would prevent your database to fetch and sort the inactive parts.